# NodeJs sails model replacing existing table

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, model, sails.js, sails-mongo

Hello people below is my model code for an user table...

```
module.exports = {

attributes: {
firstName: 'string',
lastName: 'string',
age: 'integer',
birthDate: 'date',
emailAddress: 'email'
}
};
```

It is creating `user` table with the above mentioned attributes..but after after we insert some data from back end to database table `user` ... after restarting sails / nodejs .. it starts replacing the user table, so that all data inside `user` will be lost... how to fix this? so that it does not create the same table if it already exists...

Comment: Which sails version are you using ?

Comment: @user3436481 : I hope the answer below satisfies your requirements ? If yes, its a good practice and recommended to mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the model settings for this. Either change your model like this:

```
module.exports = {

    migrate: 'safe',

    attributes: {
        firstName: 'string',
        lastName: 'string',
        age: 'integer',
        birthDate: 'date',
        emailAddress: 'email'
    }

};
```

Or if you are using sails version 0.10.x, then you can also make this setting global by changing the config/models.js file:

```
module.exports.models = {
  migrate: 'safe'
};
```

Local settings in each model if present will override global settings